# Why won't my font load?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, truetype

I have the following font-face set up in CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dtdt_menu';
    src: url('../fonts/Chalkduster.ttf');
}
```

and a menu setup as follows:

```
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'dtdt_menu';
}
```

This don't work at all. But when i change the font-face to the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dtdt_menu';
    src: url('../fonts/Pacifico.ttf');
}
```

This works as it should, but the `Pacifico.ttf` font is located in the same folder and has chmod 755 just as `Chalkduster.ttf`. Why won't `Chalkduster.ttf` load? I don't understand it, since it has the exact same rights as the other custom font which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-family` values must be the same. You also need to find out the what the actual font name is for CSS `font-family` most of the time it's the same as the font file name, but it can be something else too. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), and use the [Web Font Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to make the web font to work on all browsers.

Chalkduster

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Chalkduster';
    src: url('../fonts/Chalkduster.ttf');
}
.menu ul {
    font-family: 'Chalkduster';
}
```

Pacifico

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
    src: url('../fonts/Pacifico.ttf');
}
.menu ul {
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a path issue. Working on my local computer, I entered ../ in front of the Fonts folder so the path was:
../Fonts/font-name.ttf
That solved my problem with the font loading.